# Active Record Where Clause For Relation In Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two Models `User` and `Site`. The User has category like 'basic and premium'. The user has relation to sites one -> many (i.e one user can have more than one sites). Now i want to select sites of premium user. Can someone tell me how to use where clause in `ActiveRecord` to achieve this?

Comment: Is category a column in users table? Or category isn't another model per se?

Comment: @Vijay yes you can use where clause on sites as well. Note: `where clause will give you a collection of records and not a single record`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select sites of premium user

This will do

```
User.includes(:sites).where('users.category = ?', 'premium')
```

***Update***

> If sites also have categories like 'wordpress or joomla', how do i
>   apply where clause to select only wordpress sites of premium users

For that you need to tweak the query like this

```
User.includes(:sites).where('users.category = ? and sites.category = ?', 'premium','wordpress')
```

Comment: Now if sites also have categories like 'wordpress or joomla', how do i apply where clause to select only wordpress sites of premium users .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It helped me to solve my problem :).

Comment: but when i run the query it shows only users not sites.

Comment: @Vijay Which query you ran?

Comment: Then second one. User.includes(:sites).where('users.category = ? and sites.category = ?', 'premium','wordpress')

Comment: @Vijay Very weird. did you double check the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81252/discussion-between-vijay-and-pavan).

Answer (score 0):

As you said that `category` is a column, so Rails automatically generates the following method for you:

```
User.find_by_category("basic")
```

If you do not want to use this, you can use `where` method, in which you have to send a key-value pair like following:

```
User.where(:category => "basic")
```

And when you have found a `user` with the category you desired, you can simply call `sites` on it to get all the associated sites with a particular user.

Comment: I need to select sites. Not users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
@user_ids = User.where(category: 'premium').pluck(:id)
@sites = Site.where(user_id: @user_ids)
```